# Problem with Screws/Hinges on laminate door

Tags: carpentry

Fitting a finished laminate door. Routered hinges and pre-drilled before screwing. Screws nearest the edge of the door caused a ripple as if screw was pushing it the laminate out. checked screws were straight. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a picture handy?

Comment: The MDF or chipboard on laminates is not very compressible or forgiving. Sound like you needed a larger pilot hole.

Answer (score 1):

You need a bigger pilot hole for sure. If needed, point the holes inward a bit but not much.